# Div with images inside get weird effect

Tags: css

I have some containers side by side that might be empty or might have a image inside.

The problem is, instead of just acting like a simple window, the image goes outside the div and the other divs go down. How can I fix this issue? My code:

```css
div {
  background-color: lightGray;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px
}

img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 80px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="girrafe.png">
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fixed height for image is greater than fixed height for div?

Comment: Yes it is, Armin.

Comment: And what does "simple window" mean? You want only part of an image to be shown? You want to reduce original size, leave it the same? You want it to fit the lower value to 100%? There are many options...

Comment: I want the size of the div to be the same as the others so probably make it like it was a frame with a scrollbar.

Comment: Then I think combination of suggested answers is right fit for you. Take the one with scrollbar, but make sure your image is not distorted. So either leave one of the values as automatic, or add horizontal scrolling too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed height of image is greater than the fixed height of div.

Also you can make it hide/scroll by using Overflow property.

**EDIT**

Try this...

Here i used [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):

The object-fit CSS property specifies how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box established by its used height and width.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div {
      background-color: lightGray;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 150px;
      width: 100px
    }
    img {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The image is scretched which I don't want.

Comment: How about scrolling into the container?

Comment: Yes, I think the answer with the overflow-y looks godd unless there's something better that I don't know of.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the image overflowing its parent if it is bigger than it, add `overflow:hidden` to the rules for your `div`.

```css
div{
    background-color:lightGray;
    display:inline-block;
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px
}
img{
    height:300px;
    width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://unsplash.it/80/300/?random"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Alternatively, to allow the image to overflow its parent but keep the tops of all the divs aligned, add `vertical-align:top` to the rules instead.

```css
div{
    background-color:lightGray;
    display:inline-block;
    height:150px;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px
}
img{
    height:300px;
    width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://unsplash.it/80/300/?random"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Or, finally, if you just want to force the image to be contained within its parent then set the `height`, `max-height`, `width` & `max-width` properties of the `img` rule like so:

```css
div{
    background-color:lightGray;
    display:inline-block;
    height:150px;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px
}
img{
    height:auto;
    max-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div><img heigt="80" src="https://unsplash.it/80/300/?random" width="300"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Unlike other two solutions, this one at least won't distort image.

Comment: That way I can't see the bottom of the image.

Comment: See the alternative solution I've added. If neither solution solves your issue then please edit your question to clarify exactly what you're looking to achieve.